# Creating a basic programming language - resources?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I don't know if this is the right SE site for this question, if not, I would appreciate anyone who could point me in the right direction.

For my college project (UK college ~ high school) I want to design a basic programming language. It won't have all the necessary functionality, but enough to write some basic programs on the Console. I want to make it interpreted as I've heard how horribly complex compiled languages are; object-oriented because I only know VB.NET and am most comfortable with OOP; and my goal is to create a simple language which is easily learned by non-programmers.

I've been looking around but struggling to find helpful resources that explain about creating programming languages in any good detail. I'd really appreciate any online resources you can suggest - they have to be free - if there are similar StackOverflow questions that I missed, in-depth online articles or tutorials, extracts from free online textbooks... anything you think might be useful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Comment: You might have a look at this, to: www.antlr.org. Antlr is a parser generator.

Comment: Starting with an OOP language is not a good idea. Start with something conceptually simpler, maybe a functional language or an imperative language

Comment: Also, notice that for simplicity's sake you should first think about building an _interpreter_, a compiler is harder, but fine as long as you get the basic concepts right

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, as far as functional or imperative languages go, which languages would you recommend for comparison? I don't know offhand what either of those paradigms mean, and wikipedia isn't proving helpful. Also, why is OOP a bad idea?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, yes, that's why I said in the OP I wanted to make the language interpreted not compiled, as I've heard elsewhere that an interpreter is easier to build.

Comment: Scheme is an example of an (impure) functional language, you can write an interpreter for it in about 300-400 lines of code (SICP shows you how to in chapter 4). Pascal is an example of an imperative language. As I mentioned above: OOP is a bad idea because it'll be harder, more complex to implement

Comment: Would you recommend creating a functional language, then?

Comment: @LeoKing that's right, it'll be easier

Answer (score 5):

Look no further than [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) - this book will enlighten you about the principles of programming and programming languages, and in its last two chapters it'll teach you how to build an interpreter and a compiler for the [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) programming language - written in Scheme.

I can assure you, the material in the book will profoundly change the way you think about computation. Coupled with the [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) IDE, you'll have a great environment to learn how to create your own programming language starting from first principles.

Another recommended book would be [Essentials of Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062798), although the material covered there is a bit more advanced. It'll also show you how to implement feature-rich languages in Scheme, this time including typed languages and an OOP language.

Comment: Scheme clearly isn't OOP (it's impure functional) but OOP is probably a bad idea for a first compiler/interpreter project anyway. Scheme is a good option. Another traditional option is a subset of Pascal, but that tends to mean using scanner and parser generator tools (lex and yacc or similar). Scheme syntax is simple enough to avoid that issue.

Comment: @Steve314, why is OOP a bad idea for a first project? In any case, I don't feel comfortable using another paradigm - I've only been programming a year and I'm still trying to settle into OOP.

Comment: @LeoKing because there are simpler programming paradigms, more appropriate for learning. Writing a programming language is no easy task, so the simpler you keep things, the easier it'll be

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but Óscar is basically right. OOP needs you to deal with inheritance hierarchies, late dispatch and other issues. A simpler language will avoid those extra issues, but still leave you plenty to work on for a first interpreter. Personally, IIRC the first "interpreter" I wrote many years ago wasn't much more than an arithmetic expression evaluator.

Comment: BTW - if you can write a formula for a spreadsheet cell, you can write in a (very simple) functional language.

Answer (score 2):

Aho-Ulman have an excellent (and very deep) book on compilers.
[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)

However, if you want a quick recipe for writing a simple compiler, it might be too deep. Still, it may be good to have it for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I worry that it may indeed be too deep - I'm not sure I'd know where to start with all this material! Plus, I'd rather go with interpreted than mess around with a compiler - I get the impression that an interpreted language would be easier to change later.

Comment: Well-designed interpreters and compilers ought to be about as easy to change with respect to the source language.  They differ only what they do after they've digested the source.

Answer (score 1):

Look for parser and lexer generators if you want help parsing the langauge itself.

Traditional Linux tools, lex and yacc, were a good choice.  Linux has bison and flex, which are their Linux-variants.

If the langauge is simple enough, they may not be necessary.

I don't know any good references.  Perhaps this list of things the interpreter needs will help:

- Conditional Statements (e.g. "if")
- Branch statements (e.g. "goto")
- Variable storage and assignment statements
- At least a simple expression evaluator (e.g. if I want to set X=1+1, it needs to set X to 2)
- Input and output (e.g. read and write statements or functions)

See http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_5.html for a simple example program using bison which parses and executes the functions of a basic calculator. Here's a copy of the example from that page:

```
input:    /* empty */
        | input line
;

line:     '\n'
        | exp '\n'  { printf ("\t%.10g\n", $1); }
;

exp:      NUM             { $$ = $1;         }
        | exp exp '+'     { $$ = $1 + $2;    }
        | exp exp '-'     { $$ = $1 - $2;    }
        | exp exp '*'     { $$ = $1 * $2;    }
        | exp exp '/'     { $$ = $1 / $2;    }
      /* Exponentiation */
        | exp exp '^'     { $$ = pow ($1, $2); }
      /* Unary minus    */
        | exp 'n'         { $$ = -$1;        }
;
%%
```

Comment: Is that the main thing I need to do, write out a grammar and then use a parser/lexer generator? I'm convinced there must be more to it than that :p.

Comment: @Leo - for a serious compiler, there's a lot more to it, but the compilers/interpreters 101 lesson is about manipulating abstract syntax trees (and similar trees that technically aren't ASTs, but plenty of people call them that anyway). However, the traditional compilers/interpreters courses are substantially about how you get an (abstract) syntax tree from the source text - in the early days, this was the difficult thing, and if you want to understand how scanning and parsing work (rather than just let the tool do it) they're still non-trivial.

Comment: @Leo - the parser/lexer gets you only parsed input for the interpreter.  Then code needs to be added to implement the operations.  That code can go in the parser itself, for example calling a function after a specific statement has been successfully parsed.  With that said, for a basic langauge, it should be possible to implement the guts with a small amount of code.